# Extract excel a value from multiple same key

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my array

```
Number  LastVisitSite   bonus homeclub

1000001 Beta             589   Delta

1000001 Delta            324   Delta

1000001 Alpha            456   Delta

1000002 Tango            78    Delta

1000002 Delta            98    Delta

1000003 Delta            745   Delta

1000004 Delta            142   Delta 

1000004 Emerald          50    Delta
```

---

I will create Excel sheet with following table

```
Number   Bonus

1000001

1000002

1000003

1000004
```

I will create a Excel formula at Bonus filed

If Last Visit Site = Home club then get bonus point else put

So the result should be as below:

```
Number   Bonus

1000001  324

1000002  98 

1000003  745

1000004  142
```

I tried use lookup but it doesn't get the result what I want.

Please advise.
Best regards,
Hong Yaw

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
      --($A$2:$A$9=F2),
      --($B$2:$B$9=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$9,4,FALSE)),
     $C$2:$C$9)
```

Basically what it does is find the rows in the primary table where the ID is equal to the current row and `LastVisitSite` is equal to  `homeclub` for that number (matches will return 1, misses 0). It then multiples that array by the `bonus` column, resulting in the sum of the bonuses for each time `LastVisitSite` equals `homeclub` (note that this will double-count if there have been more than one home games).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first I thought I need to omit the --. Only later I realised is part of the formula. I got the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `SUMPRODUCT()` function you can do multiple compares (Number is what you want and Lastsitevisit=homeclub).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$9=$D$2:$D$9),--($A$2:$A$9=A13),$C$2:$C$9)
```

(assuming your data range is in A1:D9 and your result range is in A12:B16, so the reference to A13 = 1000001

Here's a great reference for `SUMPRODUCT()` tricks:  http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/

Comment: Thanks for the good reference. Your method also got me the result. :)